# Loop in a loop, can I do this better?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I use **Python 2.7** and **Beautiful Soup 3.2** and I got the following scraper to get the stream URLs:

```
# Import the classes that are needed
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# URL to scrape and open it with the urllib2
url = 'http://www.wiziwig.tv/broadcast.php?matchid=219751&part=sports'
source = urllib2.urlopen(url)

# Turn the saved source into a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)

for tr in soup.findAll('tr', {'class': ['broadcast']}):
    stationName = tr.findAll('td')[1].text

    for trBelow in tr.findAllNext('tr'):
        curClass = trBelow['class']
        if curClass == 'broadcast':
            break

        kindStream = trBelow.findAll('td')[0].text
        streamUrl = trBelow.find('a', {'class': 'broadcast go'})['href']
        streamQuality = trBelow.findAll('td')[2].text
        streamRating = trBelow.find('div', {'class': 'rating'})['rel']

        print stationName, kindStream, streamQuality, streamRating, streamUrl
```

This is working perfectly and gives the following output:

```
BWIN Flash 650 Kbps 100 http://forum.wiziwig.eu/threads/1847-BWIN-Info
BWIN Flash 675 Kbps 100 https://sports.bwin.com/en/sports?wm=3448325&zoneId=1068792
Bet365 Flash 650 Kbps 100 http://forum.wiziwig.eu/threads/6258-Bet365
Bet365 Flash 675 Kbps 100 http://www.bet365.com/?affiliate=365_014110
TRK Ukraine+ AceStream 1250 Kbps 100 acestream://94879770520f2e9db2146d0eca59204bfbd72cbe
TRK Ukraine+ AceStream 1251 Kbps 75 http://aviatortv.org/football_ua_plus/
Arenavision1 Sopcast 2000 Kbps 75 sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/143876
Arenavision3 AceStream 2000 Kbps 75 acestream://a53a380706846bfc6667e21a1485dedb78b9674b
Arenavision3 AceStream 2001 Kbps 75 http://avod.me/play/a53a380706846bfc6667e21a1485dedb78b9674b
Dazsports Ace2 AceStream 850 Kbps 100 acestream://d293c82146aa6c2904e45ff305ae0f38dc5b329d
Dazsports Ace2 AceStream 851 Kbps 75 http://dazsports.org/ace2.html
Digi Sport1 [RO] Sopcast 1500 Kbps 100 sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/146141
Digi Sport1 [RO] Sopcast 1500 Kbps 100 sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/124992
Digi Sport1 [RO] Sopcast 1501 Kbps 100 sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/139777
Digi Sport1 [RO] Sopcast 1501 Kbps 100 sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/110152
Pole Position1 [NL] AceStream 1000 Kbps 100 acestream://86fd521d30e9319198b75121761eccf260fef0cb
Pole Position1 [NL] AceStream 1001 Kbps 75 http://polepositionweb.org/?page_id=6 popup
Solodeportes Veetle Veetle 850 Kbps 100 http://veetle.com/index.php/widget/index/E47CFF6CB6A770852515B8B30C2E30F6/0/true/default/false
Livesports4u4 Flash 225 Kbps 75 http://livesport4u.com/stream4.html
Cricfree Flash2 Flash 175 Kbps 75 http://cricfree.tv/live-golf-streaming-ch2.php
Njtvx9 Flash 175 Kbps 75 http://nutjob.eu/njtvx9.html
Igoal C+ Liga Flash 175 Kbps 75 http://ana1.me/liga+.html
Soccertoall2 [PT] Flash 175 Kbps 75 http://soccertoall.net/index.php?channel=2
Tugalive1 Flash 175 Kbps 75 http://www.tugalive.eu/p/live-1.html
Diresport1 Flash 175 Kbps 75 http://diresportt.blogspot.com.es/
Footstream11 Flash 175 Kbps 75 http://www.footstream.tv/channel11.html
Lag10 (8) Flash 150 Kbps 50 http://lag10.com/channel8
ANA STV2 Flash 400 Kbps 75 http://ana1.me/STV2.html
ANA STV2 Flash 400 Kbps 75 http://bliner.tv/sporttv2pt.html
Livesoccerhd4 Flash 225 Kbps 75 http://livesoccerhd.tv/l4.html
Stvstreams Ace HD1 AceStream 1500 Kbps 100 acestream://750acfc788e12220dbd57188505eae08f566281e
Stvstreams Ace HD1 AceStream 1500 Kbps 100 http://stvstreams.com/acestreams/stv-hd/
Btsportshd12 Flash 200 Kbps 75 http://www.btsportshd.com/stream12.php
Ana Stream1 Flash 175 Kbps 75 http://ana3.me/STREAM1.html
Onlinesoccer2all (13) Flash 175 Kbps 75 http://online--soccer.eu/channel13.html
Hdfoots6 Flash 175 Kbps 75 http://hdfoots.com/stream6.html
```

But I was wondering if I did this like it should or is there a better way without doing the next loop `for trBelow in tr.findAllNext('tr'):` and then break out of it when it hits the specific class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably just iterate over the `<tr>` items:

```
station_name = ''
for tr in soup.findAll('tr'):
    if tr['class'] == 'broadcast':
        station_name = tr.findAll('td')[1].text
    else:
        # Your current extraction code
        print stationName, kindStream, ....
```

This way the code is a little bit clearer, I guess.

On the other hand... looks like you have a quick script that works. It'll break quicker through changes in the html output of the actual page than though bugs in your code. So if it works, it works, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

I think your implementation is great already.
Just a quick question, what if I wanted to reuse some of the contents I received?
I assert "Soup" is not using a built in cache for this and if I wanted to re run through
this loop It'd re traverse the nodes.

Here's my take:

```
with soup:
  tr_elements, tr_belows, collection = findAll('tr', {'class': ['broadcast']}) \
                                       [tr.findAllNext('tr') for tr in tr_elements], {}
  collection['station_names'] = [tr.findAll('td').text[1] for tr in tr_elements]
  collection['kind_streams'] = [trb.findAll('td').text[0] for trb in tr_belows]
  ## and so fourth.
  print dict(collection)
```

this will still need some work as it can't scan a 'broadcast' node inside the others. In addition, the complexity on my approach can use some work.